# How to configure Firebase Admin to initialize app based on environment of the request?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-admin

working on a react native application that has 3 variants, development, staging, and production. i only have two firebase projects. one is used for production and the other for development and staging

i have an express server that uses the firebase Admin SDK. im interested in configuring the server to initialize the appropriate project based on the environment the request came from. the problem is, the server wont know which project to initialize until it gets a request.

i was thinking of making a custom middleware and using a function exported from the firebase config file, something maybe like...

middleware:

```
const {initAdminByEnvironment} = require('./config')

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const requestorEnvironment = req.header('Requesting-Environment')

  initAdminByEnvironment(requestorEnvironment)

  next()
}
```

config:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
console.log("projectId: " + process.env.PROJECT_ID);

function initAdminByEnvironment(env) {
 if (env == 'production') {
   // init prod config
 } else {
   // init dev/staging config
 }
}

module.exports = {admin: admin, initAdminByEnvironment: initAdminByEnvironment }
```

this would force admin initialization to go through middleware first i would guess, and then when 'admin' is required by other routes, the proper config is accessed. is there a better way to accomplish this that would determine the admin config based on the requesting environment?

Answer (score 1):

I needed only two environments - local and production. For that I am using 'process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR' like below:

```
let environment = "development";
if (process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR !== true &&
  process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR.toLowerCase() !== "true") {
  environment = "production";
}
```

Since you have an request object, I think you can check by domain name.

Also you may want to check if Node files will be cached once the app is updated in firebase-functions (or are they initialised each time per request.) It will be better if you read the config file dynamically instead of top level require function.

You can also check if hosting multiple functions in firebase would be an option for you. Based on the type request, you can forward the request for a particular user to another app with admin features.